# Get Wordpress options while on a Paypal IPN call

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, paypal-ipn

I have successfully implemented a Paypal IPN listener in a file that resides in the same directory as the other files that make the Wordpress theme. However, I want the user to set some variables, e.g the `$receiver_email` from Wordpress' `get_option()` function through their customized dashboard. I have tried loading `wp-load.php` and it recognizes the `get_option()` function and the value I'm trying to pass as well, **BUT** only when I access the file directly through navigating there with the browser URL bar. Thus, I'm unable to get a  VERIFIED payment through IPN even though I set the right inputs at the IPN simulator panel. Somehow, the `get_option()` value is not being passed during the IPN call. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you setup your IPN listener slightly different and point it directly to a WordPress instance. For example, set your notify URL to domain.com/?paypal_ipn_result=1 and then have something like this in a plugin file or your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_template_redirect' );
function my_template_redirect() {
    if ( ! isset( $_REQUEST['paypal_ipn_result'] ) )
        return;

    // Your IPN stuff goes here, you can use get_option and other things.
}
```

You can even use an earlier hook than template_redirect to get WordPress to not ever parse your request. Perhaps the `request` filter can be a good place, or maybe even `init`.

Comment: could you clarify how the paypal (or any other IPN) info is then available after the `// Your IPN stuff goes here` ?  For instance, if XML code was sent to this IPN listener, how do I access that incoming code?  It isn't a variable, so I'm a little unclear.

Comment: PayPal gets back to you using the POST method, so look in the `$_POST` array for the available PayPal data.

Comment: Great thanks!  I ended up needing `file_get_contents('php://input')` to give me the raw $_POST data, since I'm not using Paypal and am getting XML posted back to me.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your site domain has public access and if any firewall restriction